# How can i tinker my neural network to learn stronger on rare events?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, machine-learning, regression

I am training a neural network on a regression problem.

Most of the time the **actual y** (label) has the same value (say ~0.2) and only in rare cases the **actual y** is very different (say 2.0 or -2.0)

After training the neural network obviously performs very well on average by allways predicting **(predicted y)** a number around 0.2, mostly independant on the input.
However, it is still very bad on predicting when the **actual y** should be different.

At the moment i am improving the situation by training the neural network mostly on situations where y is far from the average y and filtering out situations where y is close to the average y.

Can you think of any better way to make the neural network learn stronger on rare events? (e.g. by using a different cost function other than MSE, ...)

*Additional information:*

*The neural network is supposed to learn the immediate rewards on a reinforcment learning environment.

the nn maps actions+states to the expected immediate reward.

most of the time the immediate reward is the same. (because the agent gets punished on every step it takes)*

Comment: This seems to be related to the question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/321831/247274), and I stand by my answer there.